# Count numbers in a range where count of 3s=count of 6s=count of 9s

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

Here is the problem description

A number is said to be a 369 number if

1-The count of 3s is equal to count of 6s and the count of 6s is equal to count of 9s.

2-The count of 3s is at least 1.

For Example 12369, 383676989, 396 all are 369 numbers whereas 213, 342143, 111 are not.

Given A and B find how many 369 numbers are there in the interval [A, B]. Print the answer modulo 1000000007.

Constraints

T<=100

1<=A<=B<=10^50

Here is my code

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    #define MOD 1000000007
    long long  DP[52][18][18][18][2];
     char  a[100],b[100];
     long long t;
     string num;
    long long  solve(long long  pos,long long cn3,long long cn6,long long cn9,long long  f)
    {
        if(cn3>=18||cn6>=18||cn9>=18)
            return 0;
        if(pos==(int)num.size())
        {
            if(cn3==cn6&&cn6==cn9&&cn3>=1)
                return 1;
        return 0;
        }

        if (DP[pos][cn3][cn6][cn9][f]!=-1) 
            return DP[pos][cn3][cn6][cn9][f]%MOD;
        long long  res=0;
        long long lmt;
        if(f==0)
            lmt=num[pos]-'0';
        else lmt=9;
        for(int dgt=0;dgt<=lmt;dgt++)
        {
            int nf=f;
            if(f==0 && dgt<lmt) nf=1;
             res+=(solve(pos+1,(dgt == 3) + cn3, (dgt == 6) + cn6, (dgt == 9) + cn9,nf)%MOD);
            res%=MOD;
        }

        return DP[pos][cn3][cn6][cn9][f]=res;

    }
    long long int solve1(string x)
    {
        num=x;
        memset(DP,-1,sizeof(DP));
        long long int result=solve(0,0,0,0,0);
        return result;
    }
        int main()
        {

            cin>>t;

            while(t--)
            {
    cin>>a>>b;
                long long ans=solve1(b)-solve1(a);
                  int sz = strlen(a), c3 = 0, c6 = 0, c9 = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
      if(a[i] == '3') c3++;
      if(a[i] == '6') c6++;
      if(a[i] == '9') c9++;
  }
  if(c3 == c6 and c6 == c9 and c3 != 0) 
      ans++;
        cout<<(ans)%MOD<<"\n";
            }
    return 0;
    }
```

It is giving wrong answer although I checked it with right code it is giving same answer for common test cases.

The approach which I used was digit dp. Here is the link for that https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53960

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Why would you need a `long long  DP[52][18][18][18][2];` to count digits in numbers?

Comment: I am solving using digit dynamic programming.Since there are atmost 51 digits ,the maximum number of 3s can be 17 because all other counts have to be same.

Comment: I dont understand what is the "dynamic" part here, tough I'll need some time to understand your code in detail

Comment: Here is the link to understand digit dp https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53960

Comment: `1<=A<=B<=10^50` -- Come on now.  You know that there is a mathematical trick to this question, and it doesn't involve loops.  You really expect to loop 10^50 times?  You need to realize the question you got from that site, and basically any question from a site like that one is designed to have naive solutions that will only work for small cases.  There is always a trick to these questions, whether it is a math trick, a special data structure or algorithm, etc.

Comment: You can read the link which I posted above . I am not exactly looping 10^50 times.

Comment: it is rather unclear why you think you need a DP approach. You never encounter the same number twice. I have the impression taht you artificially introduced the need for DP by calculating `solve1(b)-solve1(a);` which is not the most efficient approach to start with

Comment: if you already solved for `b` then you do not need to solve for `a` anymore. Ok, you can use DP to make use of that fact, but you should rather rethink how you approach the problem. As Paul said, there are easier ways to count such numbers

Comment: Because DP is calculating answer from 0 to b . So first I am calculating from 0 to b and then 0 to a .Ideally it should be a-1 but since input  is a string so I didnt subtract -1 from it.Instead I check if a is a 369 number or not then I add +1 to the answer

Comment: @Ash *I am not exactly looping 10^50 times* --  So how many times are you looping with such a large maximum value?  If you don't know, then my point has been made.   
 Your're the one trying to implement this "digit dp" stuff, so you should know right away what the maximum is.  Is it a million?  10?  A billion?  Again, if those astronomical constraints are part of the problem, then the solution has to be some sort of math trick to reduce the problem space down drastically.

Comment: I am looping the length of the number not the number itself .It would be better understandable if you read the link which I posted above.

Comment: And the length of the number has a max of  `10^50`.  Unless you're a time lord, your program will never end if it loops that many times.

Comment: By length I mean the number of digits in a number. So 10^50 has 51 digits. Number is <=10^50 .

Comment: What does "how many 369 numbers are there in the interval [A, B]" mean? The interval is over an array of digits I suppose? Is a number in the interval when it is consecutive in there, or is any subset fine? If the same number occurs twice, is it counted twice? If subsets are fine, do they keep the order or are permutations allowed? Maybe do an example of what the question means. Other than that, explain your code, I will certainly not reconstruct what it does, especially when it has indescriptive names like `lmt`.

Comment: For example if A=1 and B=1000, the numbers are 369,396,639,693,936,963. The answer is 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for wrong answer is that solve(b)-solve(a) can be negative and I was not adding MOD to the ans variable